# Quasar compile error postcssrc.js and babel.config.js missing

Tags: babeljs, postcss, quasar

When i ran quasar dev after a fresh quasar installation, the error: Can't find the module ....".postcssrc.js"  and  ..."babel.config.js"

After a few hours trying and searching on the internet finally fix that issuse, so you need to create a new empty file at the root of your project folder called .postcssrc.js, after try to compile, the error config.babel.js module isn't found, and to fix this error, renamed the file babel.config.cjs to babel.config.js and after these two tricks, everything works great!

Hope it can be helpful!